# Flashing Win 10 iot on pi2

Tags: raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I get error while trying to flash an sd card with win 10 iot core.

used this to flash
`dism.exe /Apply-Image /ImageFile:flash.ffu /ApplyDrive:\\.\PhysicalDrive1 /SkipPlatformCheck`

i get error 87

while the dism version is 10.0.9926.0

am i doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Windows version do you use?

You can try to get a fresh copy of the DISM.exe from the "Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit (ADK) RC for Windows 10" package:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=526740

The package should contain version 10.0.10075.0 which should work fine, see that article (even without having the Windows 10 Preview installed):
http://postlabs.blogspot.com/2015/06/install-windows-10-iot-core-insider.html

Comment: I am on win 10 build 9926 and i ve heard that dism of this os should work fine. Where am i getting it wrong?

Comment: Not sure about that one but why not simply updating and giving it a try?